# MemoryCache over Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, service, memorycache

I'm currently investigating some code which has a cache layer which at the bottom level uses the MemoryCache class. This is a c# Windows Service app so not web/IIS. There is a section of the code which spawns off a number of threads in which it creates and executes some code in a POC to perform some calculations. These are then stored in the above mentioned cache layer. What is been seen is it looks like cached values seem to be getting stored per thread and not at apication level.  I thought that MemoryCache was a Singleton that would sit out side of the individual threads.

Can anybody confirm this behaviour would be expected?

Many thanks for any comments.

Answer (score 3):

A [`MemoryCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is thread-safe but there is no reason to assume it's a singleton. If you want different threads to access the same MemoryCache instance you need to give them all a reference to the same instance (either as a singleton (really  bad) `static` (still bad) or through argument passing as dependency injection (good)).

The *simple* way to do it (which does use global state) is to access the *default* memory cache:

```
var cache = MemoryCache.Default; // not really a good idea and harder to test, works
```

You can [find the specific docs here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.default(v=vs.110).aspx). Make sure to [configure it in your app/web.config file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd941872(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You say global state is bad, yet your example shows how to retrieve it from a global member, hmm..

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I'm giving OP alternatives (global and DI), and my opinion about them (DI is sane, global is really bad). I'm leaving it up for OP to decide. I can't really _demonstrate_ DI here nor it is in the scope of this answer to teach it - so I do what I can by advocating it over global state.

Comment: I think a little example of injecting it using constructor injection wouldn't take too much time :) But you're right, that isn't the main goal of the question.

Comment: Try twitter. I don't use my FB at all.